# Div overlay other divs in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a container in which there is a flex container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="over">Over</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.over {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Can the over div somehow be placed over all other divs, and the width of the content should be?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the element `position:absolute` and stretch it to take the full width of `.content`. You may also use `inline-flex` so that the width of `.content` is equal to the width of its content:

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  position:relative;
}

.over {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="over">Over</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```